# Breaker box one 120 slot left but need one for a second 220 or 240 breaker.

Tags: circuit-breaker, breaker-box

My breaker box has only one breaker slot left for a 120 v breaker. I want to ad a 2nd 220 or 240 breaker to a new outlet to plug a heater into for my basement workshop. Is there any way I can do this without having an electrician install a new box or panel?

Comment: We can help if you can give us the make and model number of the panel. Even better, post a pic of the panel with the door open and also a pic of the label.

Answer (score 1):

If your panel can take more half-height (sometimes known as "cheater" or "tandem") circuit breakers, you can replace two existing 120V breakers (on the same phase!) with a tandem pair of half-height breakers; this will then free up a slot in your panel that you can then use for a full-height 240V double pole breaker.

If your panel does not accept tandem breakers, or has all its tandem-capable slots filled already, you will need either have the panel replaced or a few circuits moved into a subpanel placed next to the main panel.

If you can't tell what your panel is capable of, the listing label (usually on the inside front cover) should provide a diagram that will mark tandem-capable slots in some fashion (you can also tell by comparing the number of circuits the panel is listed for to the number of physical breaker slots in the panel).

A further issue, as Ecnerwal helpfully pointed out, is that a heavy-duty heater may simply be too much additional load for the panel itself to handle.  In that case, you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps. It depends on exactly what you have for a breaker box now and what it's rated for. It also depends on your current loads and capacity.

Some (but not all) boxes are rated for "twin" breakers, where one slot is occupied by a breaker that has two separate handles and two separate output terminals, since it is two separate breakers in one single slot package.

If you have a box that is rated for such use, and you replace two single slot breakers with a breaker of this kind, you will have two slots free for a dual-pole breaker.

Whether you have adequate capacity for the added circuit is a different but entirely valid question - so even if all the above works out, if your current panel is loaded near capacity and you add a heavy-duty heater to it, it may overload - in which case, yes, you need to upgrade the panel and possibly the service entrance as well. Whether or not that is true depends on the loads (not breakers) you have now and the additional load you are adding.

Comment: I thank all of you who answered my question and you were able to help me understand and to realize that in my case and type of breaker box I have, that it's best that I use a smaller 120 v heater that plugs into an existing outlet. The box is at its max now and it's something that I would need to hire an electrician for. The cost just for a bigger room heater can't be justified. I was hoping there was a simple shortcut that I could do without getting zapped. I thank all of you very much for the help and advice.